# weblogic em console's Admin server/managed servers status & metrics are unavailable

Tags: weblogic, weblogic11g, weblogic12c

Weblogic em console shows "status pending" for the admin servers and managed servers, even though when they are up. It is not showing other metrics as well.

Below are the head error messages.

```
oracle.sysman.emas.sdk.model.metric.MetricsUnavailableException
at oracle.sysman.emas.sdk.model.metric.WLMetricProvider.getMetricServiceMBean(WLMetricProvider.java:313)
at oracle.sysman.emas.sdk.model.metric.WLMetricProvider.queryMetricTable(WLMetricProvider.java:364)
at oracle.sysman.emas.sdk.model.metric.WLMetricProvider.getMetrics(WLMetricProvider.java:155)
at oracle.sysman.emas.sdk.model.metric.MetricUtil.getMetrics(MetricUtil.java:271)
```

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution for this issue. This is a bug and oracle has released a patch for this BUG_13826887/Patch p13826887_111160_Generic.

1.Set ORACLE_HOME, java
2.check which opatch, opatch apply
3.restart complete weblogic

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest opening a ticket with Oracle. You could try enabling Platform MBean Server  which is in Domain home -> Advanced and restarting the domain. Usually this would fix it but without logs, its very hard to tell. Please try to provide us the sysman logs for the em.